# Difference between "ToListAsync()" and "AsAsyncEnumerable().ToList()"

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, entity-framework-core, iasyncenumerable

Function need to return `Task<List<Record>>`
Following both options are returning `Task<List<Record>>`, which one is more efficient? Is there any standard way here?

Option 1 :

```
Task<List<Record>> GetRecords()
{
    return 
    DbContext.Set<Record>.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Option 2:

```
Task<List<Record>> GetRecords()
{
    return
    DbContext.Set<Record>.Where(predicate).AsAsyncEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Highly likely it's the same operation.

Comment: Could you be clear about the namespace/assembly that this AsAsyncEnumerable comes from?  And about the C# and EF versions?  The top google results point to an oldie that "may be removed in a future release"

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes. I am using EF Core 2.2. and C# 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that this is a pre .NET Core 3.x answer.
Find an update in the comment of @IanKemp here below.

Go for option 1 `ToListAsync` as the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/71a32cfd5a8c24dde5c8938f7eee4d8a14f29f5d/src/EFCore/Extensions/Internal/QueryableExtensions.cs) of `AsAsyncEnumerable` explicitly mentions

> This is an internal API that supports the Entity Framework Core
> infrastructure and not subject to  the same compatibility standards as
> public APIs. It may be changed or removed without notice in  any
> release. You should only use it directly in your code with extreme
> caution and knowing that doing so can result in application failures
> when updating to a new Entity Framework Core release.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.extensions.internal.queryableextensions?view=efcore-2.1)  mentions

> This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not
> intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be
> removed in future releases.

Comment: Thanks @pfx Do you recommend using```Task<List<Record>> GetRecords()
{
    var records = DbContext.Set<Record>.Where(predicate).ToList();
    return Task.FromResult(records);
}
```

Comment: @NaineshPatel Also avoid `Task.FromResult` here and use the `async` features of `Entity Framework` via `ToListAsync`.

Comment: From version 3.0.0 of EF `AsAsyncEnumerable` will be made a fully public first-class citizen: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/commit/2795a00b613a5f4f23fca4ad1c53012d17adf7d3

Comment: The current documentation doesn't say that AsAsyncEnumerable is internal. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async

Comment: @pavok, That is correct. This questoin and answer are from 2019, at that point in time that was still the case, but it changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 19):

No one has actually explained the difference between `ToListAsync()` and `AsAsyncEnumerable()`.

`ToListAsync()` will fetch all of the results of the query into memory, and then return the collection of results as a single `List<T>` object. It will do this asynchronously, so that it doesn't block on I/O, but it won't return *anything* until *all* of the results are available.

`AsAsyncEnumerable()` will "yield" each result as it's available. In the OP's example, they're simply calling `ToList()`, so the result is the same. However, since C# 8.0 you could also use an "async stream" such as `await foreach`, and then act on each entity *as it's returned*. For example:

```cs
await foreach (var entity in DbContext.Set<Record>.Where(predicate).AsAsyncEnumerable())
{
    // do something with entity...
}
```

As to which is "better", it depends on your use-case. If you're just returning a few records to the caller, `ToListAsync()` should be fine.

However, suppose your query will return 10,000 records. You probably don't want to store all those in memory before you act on them, because the query might run for many seconds or even minutes and will use lots of memory.

In that case, it's probably better to use an async stream. This could be your own `async IAsyncEnumerable<T>` method which `yield`s its own results. You can then chain these together if needed.

In fact, [since ASP.NET Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/iasyncenumerable-not-buffered-by-mvc), you can return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` directly from your controller method, and it will "stream" those results back to the caller.

This makes it much more efficient to write code which operates on and/or returns a large number of records, because there's never a point where they're buffered into memory.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers my initial question.

Answer (score 9):

While the existing answer by pfx is still true for .NET Core 2.x and earlier, `AsAsyncEnumerable` has been added to .NET Core 3.x officially. See Ian Kemp's comment for further info.