# Can (or should) I use IAsyncEnumerable<T> instead of Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>> in a Web API Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iasyncenumerable

I currently have a web API that

- fetches a row of data using `FromSqlRaw(...).ToListAsync()` within a repository
- returns this data as `Ok(data.ToArray())` as `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyClass>>>` through a controller.

Now I am wondering whether I should or can use IAsyncEnumerable as a return type. The idea was to use this in the repository and the controller. However, in this (now decrepit) [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176176/difference-between-tolistasync-and-asasyncenumerable-tolist) it states it should not be used. the proposed solution here would be something like:

```
FromSqlRaw(...).AsNoTracking().AsAsyncEnumerable()
```

As for the Controller I want keep the response wrapped with `ActionResult` to explicitly set the return code. However, [that](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24061) currently doesn't seem to work.

Should I just apply the solution for the repository and consume the result as a List in my controller or just keep it as it is?

Comment: I think the answer is that a consumer of the API will never receive an awaitable as result, but just results.

Comment: As for the controller it never would, as the JSON Parser is receiving the async stream and delivers it as a singular result (there was a thread on this already but I can't find it right now). I tried to get my repository to return an async stream which is consumed by the controller into a `List<T>` using `System.linq`'s `ToListAsync()`. It works but I have no idea if this butchers the purpose of `IAsyncEnumerable` as it has to be awaited by the controller now.

Comment: Please consider updating your answer here. NET6 introduces relevant changes so the answer marked as correct is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `IAsyncEnumerable` gives you an interface for [pull-based asynchronous](https://stu.dev/iasyncenumerable-introduction/) data retrieval. In other words this API represents an iterator where the next item is fetched asynchronously.

This means that you are receiving the data in several rounds and each in an asynchronous fashion.

- Prior `IAsyncEnumerable` you could use `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`, which represents a bunch of asynchronous operations with return type `T`.
- Whereas `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` represents a single asynchronous operation with a return type `IEnumerable<T>`.

---

Let's apply these knowledge to a WebAPI:

- From an HTTP consumer point of view there is no difference between `Task<ActionResult<T>>` and  `ActionResult<T>`. It is an implementation detail from users` perspective.
- A WebAPI Controller's action implements a **request-response model**. Which means a single request is sent and a single response is received on the consumer-side.
- If a consumer calls the same action again then a new controller will be instantiated and  will process that request.

This means that the consumer of your API can't take advantage of `IAsyncEnumerable` if it is exposed as an action result type.

Comment: But the response can be continuous, for example, when you return `PushStreamContent` content.

Comment: @AgentFire Yes that's true but I think it is out of scope from the question point of view.

Comment: Thanks. So I have no reason to desire something like `ActionResult<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>`  which might be the reason it's not syntactically possible atm. However, do I still gain the advantage of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` towards `Task<Enumerable<T>>` (whatever these are) if it's consumed as a List in the controller?

Comment: @Beltway If the following conditions are met then yes, it might make sense: 1) the individual elements will be available at different time of the future 2) you don't want to wait for all of them before you start to consume the already available one.

Comment: As for 1): I am using `.AsNoTracking()` as the actuality of the data is not that important, if I understood that right it doesn't really matter.  As for 2): Isn't that generally the favourable option in terms of performance and concurrency? As long as there are no disadvantages in `IAsyncEnumerable`, which I am not aware of, I would just go for it.

Comment: @Beltway If you don't see anything against it then give it a try and measure the performance of both and then compare the results.

Answer (score 6):

In .net 6 *IAsyncEnumerable* handling for MVC was [changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/iasyncenumerable-not-buffered-by-mvc) when using *System.Text.Json*:

> MVC no longer buffers IAsyncEnumerable instances. Instead, MVC relies on the support that System.Text.Json added for these types.

It means that controller will start sending output immediately and a client may start process it as it receives chunks of the response.

Here is an example with help of [new minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

Endpoint binding:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

// this endpoint return IAsyncEnumerable<TestData>
app.MapGet("/asyncEnumerable/{count}", (int count) => GetLotsOfDataAsyncEnumerable(count));

// and this one returns Task<IEnumerable<TestData>>
app.MapGet("/{count}", async (int count) => await GetLotsOfDataAsync(count));
app.Run();
```

Controller methods:

```cs
async Task<IEnumerable<TestData>> GetLotsOfDataAsync(int count)
{
    var list = new List<TestData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        list.Add(new TestData($"{i}"));
    }
    return list;
}

async IAsyncEnumerable<TestData> GetLotsOfDataAsyncEnumerable(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        yield return new TestData($"{i}");
    }
}

class TestData
{
    public string Field { get; }

    public TestData(string field)
    {
        Field = field;
    }
}
```

*count* path variable allows to control how many data we want to retrieve in a single call.

I've tested it with *curl* command on a windows machine ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625150/6482931) is the answer explaining how to measure performance with *curl*), results for 100 entries:

```bash
                       /100        /asyncEnumerable/100
     time_namelookup:  0.000045s   0.000034s
        time_connect:  0.000570s   0.000390s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s   0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.000648s   0.000435s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s   0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  1.833341s   0.014880s
                       ---------------------
          time_total:  1.833411s  1.673477s
```

Important here to see is *time_starttransfer*, from curl manpage

> The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the first byte was just about to be transferred. This includes time_pretransfer and also the time the server needed to calculate the result.

As you can see */asyncEnumerable* endpoint started responding instantly,   of course, clients of such endpoints have to be aware of such behavior to make good use of it.

Here how it looks in a cmdline:
[image: async enumerable call in curl]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on the following: _"of course, clients of such endpoints have to be aware of such behavior to make good use of it."_ Say I was consuming this from a C# client, what exactly would that client need to do to ensure he also reads as early as possible?

Comment: In case of json, client must support streaming de-serialization of json to start processing it as soon as possible. The relatively new _System.Text.Json_ supports that. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512393/how-to-deserialize-stream-to-object-using-system-text-json-apis) addresses this problem.